# ReactNative Text Style Next Line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Simply I am trying to make 3 Texts with icons align in a column

[image: a]

I want to give the expo icons a little margin-top so they are next to each text element

Then how can I make the next line in text aligned with the text itself 
For Example The (S) in School to be vertically aligned with the (5) in 5th

```
I searched a lot on how to do that in react-native but with no luck
```

and I tried some normal CSS stuff but didn't work is it achievable?

Code :

```
  <View style={styles.cardView}>
    <Text style={styles.CardTextLayout}  > <MaterialIcons name="store" size={21} color="lightgrey" /> {item.key} </Text>
    <Text style={styles.locationText}  > <Entypo name="location-pin" size={21} color="lightgrey" />5th Settelment, Near Akhnaton School, Cairo</Text>
    <Text style={styles.locationText}  > <MaterialIcons name="description" size={21} color="lightgrey" />Breif Description about the place and what is offers</Text>

  </View>
```

Styles

```
     CardTextLayout: {
    // marginLeft: 8,
    fontSize: cardResponsiveFontSize,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#231F20',
    elevation: 8,
  },
  locationText: {
    fontSize: cardResponsiveFontSize,
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#231F20',
    elevation: 8,
  },
```

Comment: maybe add `justifyContent: "center"` to your text style

Comment: i did but it did nothing

Comment: display: "inline-flex" for the locationText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you would do that with your current code, but you can try to set it up like this.

```
<View style={styles.cardView}>
  <View style={styles.cardRow}>
    <View style={styles.cardIcon}>{put your icon here}</View>
    <View style={styles.cardText}>{put your text here}</View>
  </View>
  ...add the other 2 rows here
</View>
```

And styles

```
cardRow: {
  flexDirection: "row",
  flex: 1
},
cardIcon: {
  flex: 1
},
cardText: {
  flex: 9
}
```

And add your styles for icons and text.
You can change up the cardIcon and cardText flex ratio so that you get different width for your icon.

Comment: It's working fine but does some many view afect performance ??

Comment: I'm really new to react-native so I don't know the answer to that question, but I think view-s don't effect performance a lot, I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a wrapper view with alignItems: 'center' to make both text and icon vertical center

```
<View style={styles.cardView}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <MaterialIcons name="store" size={21} color="lightgrey" /> 
    <Text style={styles.CardTextLayout}>{item.key}</Text>      
  </View>
  .....
</View>
```

Comment: i will try it but does many views affect the perfromance of the app?

Comment: it don't think it matter in this case